# I have a headache. I have headache

Tags: articles, nouns

I have a headache. 
I have headache.

Which one should be the correct and valid sentence? 
Please explain it with reasons. 
Thanks.

Comment: A question you could answer by looking at a dictionary.

Answer (score 5):

'Headache' is countable.

So,

> I have *a* headache

This is strange, but we just need to remember it that way.

---

In BrE, some ailments such as stomach-ache, toothache, earache, etc fall under uncountable category. But in AmE, they are both [- Reference](http://www.englishgrammar.org/countable-uncountable-nouns-special-cases/).

Another [reference from MW Dictionary](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/qa/is-headache-a-count-noun) as I find:

> A count noun (or "countable noun") is a noun that can be counted, can be plural, and can be used with both singular and plural nouns. ***Headache,*** toothache, and stomachache are all count nouns because they meet those three criteria.

Comment: The English article system gives me **a** headache once in a while. (0: